# exists? returns true in the console, but not in my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to have a create action that finds a Lesson by the date and the school_id. If no Lesson exists with those parameters, then I create a new Lesson. The reason I'm not using find_by_or_create, or a similar method, is because I want to add to the goals of the Lesson if it exists, nor overwrite it.

Here's my controller, I believe that's all that's relevant:

the exists? call is never returning true, even though when I run rails console and type it into the console with the same parameters, it returns true. Same with find_by

```
def create
  find_or_create_lesson
  if @lesson.save
    flash[:success] = "Response logged"
    redirect_to @lesson
  else
    @user = current_user
    @school_options = School.all.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

  # strong params
  def lesson_params
    params.require(:lesson).permit(:school_id, :date,
                                   goals_attributes: [:id,   :user_id,
                                                      :text, :lesson_id])
  end

  # Finds a lesson with the same date and school, or creates the lesson
  def find_or_create_lesson
    search_params =  { date:      lesson_params[:date],
                       school_id: lesson_params[:school_id] }
    if Lesson.exists?(search_params)
      @lesson = Lesson.find_by(search_params)
      @lesson.goals << Goal.new(goals)
      @lesson.assign_attributes(search_params)
    else
      @lesson = Lesson.new(lesson_params)
    end
  end
```

What's going on?

Comment: Have you tried to follow *skinny controller, fat models* approach? In your case **ActiveRecord::Base#first_or_create** simplifies code a lot

Comment: I think there is no `params` in console. Can you insert `puts params` inside `find_or_create_lesson` to check if it has a value?

Comment: Your method isn't *creating* `Lesson` but rather *building* it. I would rename it for `find_or_build_lesson`.

Comment: use [`find_or_initialize_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by) instead.

Comment: What do you really mean by `is because I want to add to the goals of the Lesson if it exists, nor overwrite it.`?

Comment: @max Multiple users can submit a new Lesson form with the same date and school, but different goals. So in that case, I only want to update the goals to include the newsly created one. Looking back at it one of the flaws in my original code that might make this confusing is that the 
      `@lesson.assign_attributes(search_params)` is unnecessary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails has several finder methods like `find_or_initialize_by` and `find_or_create_by` which make it simpler to work with cases where you are dealing with a record that may or may not be persisted.

```
@lesson = Lesson.find_or_initialize_by(
  date: lesson_params[:date],
  school: lesson_params[:school_id]
)
```

### Edited.

To integrate this in your app you would do:

```
def create
  @lesson = Lesson.find_or_initialize_by(
    date: lesson_params[:date],
    school: lesson_params[:school_id]
  )
  @lesson.assign_attributes(lesson_params)

  if @lesson.save
    flash[:success] = "Response logged"
    redirect_to @lesson
  else
    @user = current_user
    @school_options = School.all.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] } # can be refactored out
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

  # strong params
  def lesson_params
    # we only really want to assign goals_attributes
    params.require(:lesson).permit(goals_attributes: [:id,   :user_id,
                                                      :text, :lesson_id])
  end
```

### on a side note:

Rails has a `collection_select` helper method which will create a select tag with options from a collection, so there is no need to manually create an array of options with `School.all.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }`.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:school_id, School.all, :id, :name) %>
```

### Added.

If you want to ensure that two lessons cannot be created on the same date for a school you should add a uniqueness constraint.

Create a DB index with a migration so that the database enforces the rule. (to avoid race conditions)

```
# db/migrations/add_index_to...
class AddIndexSchoolDateIndexToLessons
  def change
    add_index :lessons, [:date, :school_id], unique: true
  end 
end
```

Add a model validation to give user feedback.

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  validates : date, uniqueness: { scope: :school_id }
end
```

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I'm still getting the same problem from before.  Multiple Lessons are being created with the same date and school

Comment: You should add a validation to ensure the uniqueness, aside from that the possible reasons could be if you are using a `datetime` instead of a `date` column and the actual time does not match.

Comment: I added a complete example know that I know a bit more. If it still creates records it is due to some kind of mismatch between the user input (params) and the data you have stored. The most likely causes are that maybe you are sending a localized date or in some way human formatted date. In that case edit your question and add an example of the parameters.

Comment: If I validate for the uniqueness, won't that eliminate the possibility to find a Lesson by those attributes, since the form won't submit if it's not unique? And it was an issue with datetime vs. date, thanks for catching that because I would've missed it for hours on end

Comment: The validation won't let you create two records with the same `date` and `school_id` but it will let you update a lesson with new goals which is what happens if the lesson exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor to use [find_or_initialize_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by).

```
def find_or_create_lesson
   search_params =  { date:      lesson_params[:date],
                      school_id: lesson_params[:school_id] }
   @lesson = Lesson.find_or_initialize_by(search_params)
   @lesson.goals << Goals.new(goals) unless @lesson.persisted?
   @lesson.save
 end
```

Comment: Use `@lesson.persisted?` instead of `@lesson[:id].nil?`

Comment: This seems like it should work, but I'm still getting the same problem from before.  Multiple Lessons are being created with the same date and school